# Sending user data to server using http protocol

Tags: java, http, protocols

How can we send user data to server using http protocol by using other than Query string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Apache Commons HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) libraries.

Answer (score 0):

The query string is used with HTTP GET requests.
You can also use HTTP POST request.

Here is a place to start: [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use Http Post - Xml over Http Web Service.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to POST some JSON and expect JSON back using the Resty library (I'm the author yadda yadda).

```
import static us.monoid.web.resty.Resty.*;
Resty r = new Resty();
r.json(url, content(myJsonObject));
```